# Arduino Proto Shield Kit

Tags: prototyping, arduino, documentation

I have this [proto kit shield](http://store.arduino.cc/ww/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=11_29&products_id=215) - to make the history short, I bought long time ago, didn't touch it and I "found it" back today.

What I didn't find was a tutorial, assembly instructions or even a schematics. Any direction?

Comment: Which kit is it?

Comment: shield proto kit, is linked in the question :-)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the link, it seems this is intended as a prototyping board that is compatible with Arduino.

If this is the case, then there are no need for schematics or assembly instructions as they do not know what you will want to use it for, that is you decide on it's function/circuit.
I suppose there *could* be some documentation with ideas to try, like a circuit cookbook, but they would not have to be associated particularly with this board.
This is similar to stripboard, or breadboard - the idea of these coming with schematics or assembly instructions doesn't make much sense.

Once you have prototyped your circuit you could have a board made, and set the idea "in stone" (i.e. the board can only be used for that purpose and would need assembly instruction and schematic)

Comment: hm, I think the prototyping board is more to let you to assembly breadboard + arduino together. like this kit http://www.adafruit.com/products/51 (but this has instructions :-))

Comment: @VP01 - I see, I wasn't sure whether the uC was meant to be on the board or not. For the Arduino specific part you could probably follow the instructions on Adafruit or another Arduino schematic. You could maybe even forget Arduino and grab the Atmel uC (whatever Arduino uses - ATMega?) datasheet and follow instructions there.

Answer (score 0):

This board is meant to stack on an Arduino board (note in the summary on the linked page, "Requires and Arduino board (not included)") and provide space to build your custom devices. That's not to say you couldn't use it standalone and include the processor on it, but that's wasn't the design intent.